# Windows boots up with Crt key stuck

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Since yesterday my Windows PC has been acting as if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed down. It's not a hardware problem. The physical keyboard is fine and the problem persists even when typing from a remote connection with Team Viewer.

Yes, there are a thousand questions with this same problem, but it seems that there is no unique solution and I've already tried them without success.

Things that didn't work:

- Sticky Keys are disabled as well as any other accessibility option.
- I tried pressing both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and other combinations of mashing on the keyboard.
- If I open up the on-screen keyboard it shows both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys (left and right) and also the windows key as pressed down. Clicking on them does nothing, but if I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, it briefly (less than a second) shows as unpressed and then it goes back to being pressed.
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> (as per some answers to this problem) didn't solve the issue.

Thinks that worked (temporarily):

- Bizarrely, the problem is solved if I log out and log in again, but it comes back after rebooting.
- Under Keyboards, in the Device Manager there are two items, HID Keyboard Device and a Standard PS/2 Keyboard. Removing the HID Keyboard Device solves the issue, but it comes back after reboot.

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:  (1) dism.exe  /online   /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup  (2) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   and then (3) SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart when done and test .  Also update your computer BIOS.

Comment: Cool, what do these commands do?

Comment: They can repair broken infrastructure on your computer. These are the initial repair steps.

Comment: Why is the keyboard not bad? Have you actually unplugged it and used a different one? Nothing you indicated confirms it’s NOT the keyboard. TeamViewer is not a private session like Remote Desktop. It is a shared session with the console. Both keyboards are still active at the same time.

Comment: Because nothing happened to the physical keyboard and the problem also happens with the virtual keyboard and it can be solved by logging out and back in or removing that extra keyboard device. Also, since there are so many reports like mine around solved via software, then I think the default suspicion should be soft, not hard.